# How to extract data from a site using getElementbyID on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the value of a given ID and place it on a spreadsheet. I'm trying to use the getElementbyID to extract the value, but not entirely sure how to go about it. I've got the code shown below so far. However, every time I run it I get an object is not specified error. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub ServiceTagSearch2()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim webpage As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
Dim mtbl As String

ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/servicetag/1zylzf2")

Do While ie.Busy = True
Loop

Set webpage = ie.document
mtbl = webpage.getElementById("warrantyExpiringLabel")


End Sub
```

[HTML code showing warrantyExpiringLabel ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFdrE.jpg)

Comment: Try InnerText Property i.e. mtbl = webpage.getElementById("warrantyExpiringLabel").InnerText

Comment: @Bilal I've tried that, but I still get the runtime error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set when running it

Comment: You can get a better suggestion if you could post some html code where the tag with id "warrantyExpiringLabel" can be seen.

Comment: @Bilal thanks for pointing that out. I've attached a snippet of the HTML code where it shows the "warrantyExpiringLabel" id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page need a short manual break to open complete. Place this line in the line after Loop and use .innertext like Bilal wrote:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Here thinking it was some sort of syntax issue.